# for some reason it is only displaying one if statement

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

    import random

easy = ['A','V','M','P','O','E']
random.shuffle(easy)




def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

Random = Label(f1, text=easy, bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 20))
Random.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)

Entryfield = Entry(f1, font=("Chewy", 22))
Entryfield.pack(pady=105)

Begin = Button(f1, text='Begin', font=("Chewy", 24), bg="#00CDCD",
                  command=lambda: Random.pack_forget() + Begin.pack_forget())
Begin.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

Submit = Button(f1, text="Submit", bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 24), command=lambda: winlose())
Submit.pack(fill="x", side="bottom")
```

This statement is only showing incorrect either way when I press submit, I have tried other conditions such as if not and else but still displays the same statement the code only displays the label if I use !=.

```
def winlose():
    if Entryfield == Random:
        Win = ("Your answer was correct")
        tts = Label(f1, text=Win, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        tts.pack()

    elif Random != Entryfield.get():
        L = ("Your answer is wrong")
        ttr = Label(f1, text=L, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        ttr.pack()


raise_frame(f1)
root.geometry("800x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try to print what you're comparing? (Namely ``Entryfield``, ``Random`` and ``Entryfield.get()``)

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` statement is a good starting tool when troubleshooting. If you took the time to use it you would see that your comparison in your `if/elif` statements will never be true.

For example I added some print lines to your `winlose()` function like this:

```
def winlose():
    print("The Entryfield is an object called {}".format(Entryfield))
    print("The Random label is an object called {}".format(Random))
    print("The the content of Entryfield is as string: {}".format(Entryfield.get()))
```

Here is what we get in the console:

```
The Entryfield is an object called .!frame.!entry
The Random label is an object called .!frame.!label
The the content of Entryfield is a string: Test
```

It appears as tho you want to compare the list `easy` to whatever the user puts in the entry field. You can do this by using the index of the first position in the list and using `get()` on the entry field.

Try this function instead:

```
def winlose():
    if Entryfield.get() == easy[0]:
        Win = ("Your answer was correct")
        tts = Label(f1, text=Win, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        tts.pack()
    else:
        L = ("Your answer is wrong")
        ttr = Label(f1, text=L, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        ttr.pack()
```

If you really want to use the label in this comparison then you need to specify you are comparing to the text in the label and not the label object itself.

That function would look like this:

```
def winlose():
    if Entryfield.get() == Random["text"]:
        Win = ("Your answer was correct")
        tts = Label(f1, text=Win, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        tts.pack()
    else:
        L = ("Your answer is wrong")
        ttr = Label(f1, text=L, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        ttr.pack()
```

Keep in mind right now you will just pack new labels each time you hit the button so you should look at trying to avoid that. You can do this by destroying the label or updating the label instead of creating new ones each time you press the button.